# ionic - error no whitelist platform after build an apk

Tags: ionic-framework

i want to ask you, i am a newbie. i make an app with ionic and there is some php file. i cant find yet solution for my problem, my app doesnt have whitelist plugins but it have others plugin.
i've tried command for add whitelist plugins. its work, theres whitelist plugin. but when i build the project to android, there is no whitelist plugin.
i'v check the folder android/assets/www/plugins and no whitelist plugin there after i build the project. whats the problem and solution?

thank you.

note:
i have add the meta for security policy in the index.html but nothings change.

Comment: remove the platform and then re-install it. After that add the plugin again. This might help you.

Comment: I've tried to make new project and move all the file I need. Then it's build correctly, there's whitelist plugin. Also, I've add the <meta> tag and permission in Android.xml file but still cant connect to the internet(online database). Nothings wrong when open the project with my PC localhost

Comment: you need to add **inappbrowser plugin** for that.

Comment: I've tried, its not help. I have API (PHP file) in my project to send and receive data from my online database. Could be the error come from the PHP file?

Comment: try debug that on your own. comment that part of php server an run your project .if error come again than there must be some other issue.